# Testing Web API functionality with Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am developing a c# web api application.  I am trying to test the /Token (login) and the ChangePassword action.  I was able to simulate the /Token request and get the access_token from the response.  However, I am unsure of how to use fiddler to test the ChangePassword action.  If I just pass the OldPassword, NewPassword and ConfirmPassword, I get an unauthorized error, which makes sense as I have AuthorizeAttribute set as a GlobalFilter.  It seems like I have to somehow pass the access_token as well.  My question is how do I pass the access_token with the other fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Fiddler for that, but if it's a restful service I would just use Postman (free Chrome extension) or a similar restful client. In Postman you just fill out the URL, click the Headers button and fill out 2 form fields (header/value) to add the access_token to the request.

Good luck

Comment: Could you show me an example of what that string would look like?

Comment: You can add as many parameters as you want with the request, so whatever the server is expecting from the request just fill them out as key/value pairs. You listed a few examples like OldPassword, NewPassword and ConfirmPassword so just add those as parameters with whatever values you want. It's basically mimicking a form post for you, only you don't need to build a UI to test your api.

Comment: Where would I add the access_token?

Comment: That would be a Header value probably, part of the actual request object. While the other stuff is post data (like from a form).